# Error when trying to declare a Parallel task

Tags: c#, .net, windows

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
{


  public partial class Form1: Form
  {
    Parallel myParallelTask;
```

This causes the following error:

> Cannot declare a variable of static type
>   "System.Threading.Task.Parallel".

Not sure what is wrong with this declaration.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do with this "task"?  That would determine the appropriate type to use.

Answer (score 3):

[Parallel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) is a static class.  You can construct a `Task` or `Task<T>`, but `Parallel` is only used via the methods, such as `Parallel.For` and `Parallel.ForEach`, and doesn't require an instance.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel is a static type as it says, so you cannot instantiate it. You probably want to create a Task

```
Task myParallelTask;
```

Also, the suggested method for creating a Task is

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(...code...)
```